# Java counting program

Tags: java, eclipse, string, text, count

I want to make a program to count characters, words and lines from an input text and stops when read a point(.)

This i what i have done so far...

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;
    public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.print ("Enter your text: ");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String str=input.nextLine();

    int ch=0;
    int nlines=0;
    int nwords=0;

    while(!str.equals("."))
    {
        ch+=str.length();
        nlines++;
        String[] words = str.split(" "); 
        nwords = words.length;
        str=input.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of words :"+nwords);
    System.out.println("Number ofcharacters: "+ch);
    System.out.println("Number of lines: "+nlines);
    }

    }
```

What is wrong with my program?

Comment: Can you clarify what shoulb be the bahvior? Should your programm stop at a pount or if the . is in a new line?

Comment: At the beginning you use `nextLine()` but at the end of the loop you use `next()`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: If dot is concated to word, you will never find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go:

1- do you want to count a blankspace as a character? This line will count everything from your String:

```
ch+=str.length();
```

So a way to count only characters could be removing the blank spaces, like:

```
ch+=str.replace(" ", "").length();
```

2- The number of words, according to the line above, is not counting the words... it is just replacing the old value by the new value

```
nwords = words.length;
```

So, what you could do is add the values

```
nwords += words.length;
```

3- You are not counting the first line accordingly, if you do it in your way and the first String is like "My name is John.", your program will finish.

I did a very quick fix for you code, have a look on it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.print ("Enter your text: \n");

try(Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in)) {

    String str=input.nextLine();

    int ch=0;
    int nlines=0;
    int nwords=0;

    boolean stopCount = false;
    while(true)
    {
        if(str.contains(".")) {
            String[] split = str.split(".");
            if(split.length > 1) {
                str = split[0];
                break;
            }
            stopCount = true;
        }

        ch+=str.replace(" ", "").length();
        nlines++;
        String[] words = str.split(" "); 
        nwords += words.length;

        if(stopCount) {
            break;
        }

        str=input.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of words :"+nwords);
    System.out.println("Number ofcharacters: "+ch);
    System.out.println("Number of lines: "+nlines);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `next()` instead of `nextLine()`. Plus, you are not adding to nwords but overriding the previous value at each iteration. This code will work if you have a last consisting in a single ".".

```
String str = input.nextLine();

int ch=0;
int nlines=0;
int nwords=0;

while(!str.equals(".")) {        
    nlines++;
    ch     += str.length();
    nwords += str.split("\\s+").length;
    str     = input.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Number of words :"+nwords);
System.out.println("Number ofcharacters: "+ch);
System.out.println("Number of lines: "+nlines);
```

Comment: This won't work...str will never more than likely = ".". Unless "." is the only character on the line

Comment: Yes, and why would it be impossible ? He never told the "." would be in a sentence. Without more information, I keep this as it is because there is no reason it is absolutely wrong in any context.

Comment: You have to read between the lines this will obviously not work for what he is trying to do.

Comment: I'm sorry but you have no idea of that. This will be my last word.

Comment: I do have an idea of that by reading the question and I have a feeling you do too.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
while(str.charAt(i) != '.')
{
    ch++;
    if(i == 0)
    {
       nlines++;
       String[] words = str.split(" "); 
       nwords += words.length;
    }
    i++;
    if(i >= str.length())
    {
       i = 0;
       if(!input.hasNextLine())
       {
          break;
       }
       str = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Something like this should help you.  There are different ways of accomplishing this but this is one that is similar to what you were trying to do I think.

Comment: `if(ch >= str.length())` : seems weird to me. Why do you do that ? At some time of the execution, this condition will be true for sure if lines have reasonable length.

Comment: You need to get the next line when you have reached the end of the current string you could do if(ch == str.length()) it would work the same.

Comment: Sorry should be i if(i >= str.length())

Comment: It would be far easier to have an inner loop through the current line don't you think ?

Comment: No it is easier to do 1 loop.  Using loops inside loops causes O(n^2) performance (this should be avoided unless necessary) also there is no need to make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Do you realize you are looping over each character of each line, which is exactly the same of using two nested loops ? It is like looping over a matrix using only one loop, it is possible but no more readable nor faster than using nested loops. You can't dertermine complexity just by counting the number of loops. It works only for basic algorithms such as naive sort algorithms.

Comment: Yes that's good. Thank you. Now im trying to cut the words after the point. I want the program to count til the point.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your code:

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    System.out.print("Enter your text: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = input.nextLine();

    int ch = 0;
    int nlines = 0;
    int nwords = 0;

    while (!str.equals(".")) {
        ch += str.length();
        nlines++;
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        nwords += words.length;
        str = input.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Number of words :" + nwords);
    System.out.println("Number ofcharacters: " + ch);
    System.out.println("Number of lines: " + nlines);
}
```

}

Sample input and output:

> Enter your text: my name is 1
>   my name is 2
>   my name is 3
>   .
>   Number of words :12
>   Number ofcharacters: 36
>   Number of lines: 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution;

```
    int ch=0;
    int nlines=0;
    int nwords=0;
        String str;
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            str = input.nextLine();
            nlines++;
            for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
                if(ch == ' ')  // you need to check for tabs and new line
                    nwords++;
                else if(ch == '.')
                    break;
                else ch++;
            }
        }

     System.out.println("Number of words :"+nwords);
     System.out.println("Number ofcharacters: "+ch);
     System.out.println("Number of lines: "+nlines);
```